# AWS Multifactor Authentication and shiny-server

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, authentication, cloud, shinyapps

I have a shiny-server app deployed on an ec2 AWS instance.
This app uses the library `aws.s3` to perform reading/writing operation to s3 bucket.

The problem is, due to company policy reasons, i should use MFA authentication on the aws IAM users.

If i add the MFA authentication to the user used in the shiny-server instance, these will fail to download/upload data to the bucket s3 (permission denied)
R Code to read s3 bucket:

```
 Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "ACCESSKEY",
               "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "SECRETACCESSKEY",
               "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "REGION",
               "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN" = "")
 aws.s3::s3read_using(FUN, trim_ws = TRUE, object = "myobject")
```

Is there some ways to download/upload s3 files through R, i can use other methods than this one but i can't change the iam policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve on your approach here. You should not be using IAM Users to access S3 from EC2 instances, so there should not be a need for 2-factor authentication in the first place.

When accessing AWS Services, you should try to look for IAM Roles rather than IAM users, wherever possible. You can read more about different identities in the official docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html).

Among other things, AWS IAM Roles are automatically rotated behind the scenes and you should not be required to maintain or pass in AWS users credentials anywhere. This means the credentials are short lives and that reduces the impact in case they are compromised.

You can refer to this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/#:%7E:text=To%20connect%20to%20your%20S3,grants%20access%20to%20Amazon%20S3.&text=Confirm%20that%20the%20S3%20bucket,have%20a%20policy%20denying%20access.) from AWS Knowledge Center for steps to get this up and running.

Comment: I need to use R to Connect to s3. No other things

Comment: Hey, you can still continue to use R for this, just that with roles you will not have to provide any credentials. The AWS package will automatically retrive the short lived credentials for you. IAM Roles are more of a authentication method that have various scenarios that you would have to implement yourself already covered by AWS for you.

Comment: I got your point, if i have a running-up ec2 server, and my roles credentials expiry. What should i do? I should restart the ec2 instance, to get new credentials? Thank you a lot for your time

Comment: No, you don't have to. They are automatically rotated by Boto3. If you are interested in how they function here's some insight on that - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials

Comment: It is working, thank you a lot for you help. Another question, if you don't mind. Is it also possible to send to an s3 bucket, from a source outside AWS, a lot of data, on a daily basis, with a user that has a MFA authentication avoiding to insert the MFA code every time the data are sent?

Comment: That's classic complying-with-rules-but-not-folowing-it :p Anyways, Outside AWS ecosystem. say on clients browser you would have to use IAM Users and In most scenarios MFA are used to log into console. So if you are accing programatically i.e. via access and secret key, they will still go through without the need of MFA code.

Comment: the point is that i should attach an IAM policy to prevent all the actions except of                 "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "sts:GetSessionToken",). My point is, is it possible to use this policy and add other policies (i.e. on s3 bucket) to avoid the MFA authentication for that specific element ? Without changing the above policy attached to the user?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Ideally you should follow the principle of least privilege i.e. grant only what is needed and nothing more. So in this case, if you know that the ec2 instance will only ever `put` data into S3, grant only `s3:PutObject`.

Comment: Yes, but if i need to send data (from an outside AWS source) to S3 bucket and i follow the principle of least privilege, the policy that i need to attach (the one posted on the comments above) i will still need of the MFA authentication. Thank you a lot for the help, i'm really stuck on this problem ( the ec2 one is solved thanks to your advices)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217977/discussion-between-mayank-raj-and-lgndrzzz).

Comment: In case of R, you'll need to install package aws.ec2metadata otherwise the iam role wont simple work.